# glob issue to include all class files

Tags: php

I have an includes file with a few class files in:

```
|includes
|-> database.class.php
|-> user.class.php
|-> functions.php
```

etc.. Inside my functions.php I include all the class files:

```
include_once 'database.class.php';
```

I want to separate some standard files from the class files by changing the structure to:

```
|includes
|-> functions.php
|-> class
    |-> database.class.php
    |-> user.class.php
```

Thus when I attempt to use `glob`:

```
foreach (glob('/class/*.class.php', GLOB_NOCHECK) as $filename) {
    include_once $filename;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: include_once(/class/*.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/matt500b/dev2.csgoberry.com/includes/functions.php on line 13

I have to change it to:

```
glob('../../includes/class/*.class.php', GLOB_NOCHECK)
```

I want to understand the reason for this when I can just do `include_once 'class/database.class.php';` normally.

Why does glob depend on the file that a user is look at rather than including from the functions file as per the manual including? e.g. if I go deeper into a file structure:

```
|public
    |-> tournament
        |-> dir2
            |-> index.php
```

I need to use `glob('../../../includes/class/*.class.php', GLOB_NOCHECK)`

---

The functions.php file is included in my index.php file using `include '../../includes/functions.php';`

Total file structure:

```
|includes
|-> database.class.php
|-> user.class.php
|-> functions.php

|public
|-> tournament
    |-> index.php // Where the ../../includes/functions.php'; is
```

Comment: why not `include_once 'class/database.class.php` ?

Comment: @splash58 as i said, I tried doing that and it threw errors saying unable to find this directory. hence i need to do `../../class/*`

Comment: I can be wrong but think that you show not correct structure of directory tree

Comment: @splash58 i've updated my question; but the file structure is correct

Comment: You need to establish what your PHP current Working Directory is at the point your file references are failing.

Comment: @Martin why does glob require the current working directory but manually including files with `include_once` not need it?

Comment: It's seems there's something wrong with your include path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should be doing is using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (assuming your includes are within the website root) so that whatever page you're on, the PHP is referencing includes with an absolute path so making it fully flexible to any location.

So:

```
include_once '../../class/database.class.php';
```

becomes

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/class/database.class.php";
```

and the same method can be applied to all your includes and relative path functions (such as `glob`) in any page on your website.

**WHY**?

PHP uses the current directory as the "base" of path folders if the folder is not absolutely specified.

So if your path you give PHP is detected as an absolute reference such as `/home/website/public_html/` then the absolute is used, otherwise PHP uses the [current working directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) . You can manually change the PHP current working directory but really, that's still a *relative* change so it's more safe and flexible to instead reference file addresses as absolutely as possible.

Included files use the directory location of the file they are included in. The current working directory is (if not altered manually) the directory of the file that includes, rather than of the file being included.

Comment: includes files are outside the public directory due to database connections

Comment: Then you could manually `DEFINE` a value for the path address such as /home/accountname/includesfolder/` as the `ROOTPATH` Defined value (for example)

Comment: As you said, defining the path to my folder worked fine.

Comment: note this approach will fail with aliased locations, such as http://www.example.com/~username. use `__DIR__` for better portability.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I'm confused. Which part would fail with aliases?

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this error, which explains how includes work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory